# Angularfire2 ng5.0 authentication signing out immediately after sign in

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to migrate my Angular/Firebase application from angular 4 to 5. Almost immediately after login using AngularFire.auth , a user is logged out again. By subscribing to `afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged()` I'm confident that it's a logout operation occurring. Has anyone experienced similar? Or have I just messed up my authentication in some way?

Thanks in advance

Angular @ 5.0.0
Angularfire2 @ 5.0.0-rc.6

Here is a sample login function:

```
googleLogin() {
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(result => {

  this.updateUser(result);

  this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);

}).catch(result => {
  this.toastr.error(result.message);
});
```

}

this.updateUser() updates the user object in firebase realtime db. I've tried running without it and it still logs out the user.

And to access the logged in user:

```
public getAuthedUser(): Observable<User> {

return Observable.create(observer => {
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe( authedUser => {
    if (authedUser) {
      this.db.object<User>(DB_PATH_USER + '/' + authedUser.uid).valueChanges().subscribe(u => {
        observer.next(u);
      });
    } else {
      observer.next(null);
    }
  });
});
```

}

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having trouble with this as well...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by upgrading my Angularfire2 project to

```
"@angular/fire": "5.1.0"
```